# \pause won't generate extra slides in a containsverbatim frame

Tags: beamer, verbatim, animations

It seems that the `[containsverbatim]` option when applied to a frame prevents beamer from generating intermediate slides if text animation is wanted in it. Only the first step of the animation is printed as a result.

Sample code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}[containsverbatim]
  \frametitle{Tests anim}
  blah
  \pause
  blah²
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My question then comes in two parts:

1. Is this a bug or did I miss something?
2. If it's a bug, is there a workaround?

Comment: I have the feeling that `containsverbatim` is an old option that is now deprecated (it doesn't appear in the manual); probably it's `[fragile]` that you need.

Comment: I feel really stupid right now but I'm not sure I found the correct, up to date documentation. I'd really appreciate a pointer towards the manual you use, just to be sure I'm working on an healthy basis. Sorry to have to ask that :(

Comment: If you have a Unix system, then the shell command `texdoc beamer` will present you the manual; see  http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf for an online version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The common approach to typeset frames with verbatim content is the `fragile` option, which works well with overlays:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Tests anim}
  blah
  \pause
  blah
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I hardly remember the `containsverbatim` option and my beamer manual (v3.10) does not mention it. The only reference I found for it is in the [ChangeLog of the beamer class](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/fab9b3ad3aea309a819102ca4ba2672d82baa646/ChangeLog):

> 2004-02-18 Till Tantau , Version 2.00
>
> ```
> Added:
>
> - Added a containsverbatim option to the \frame command. Should be
>     used instead of the old \frame<all:1> (which is, however, still
>     supported).
> ```

So the observed effect is not a bug, but a feature :-), as `\frame<all:1>` is the syntax in beamer to suppress all, but the first slide from a frame. The option name `containsverbatim`  seams to be pretty misleading; however, given how beamers overlay mechanism works (by scanning the frame content multiple times, which does not work well together with verbatim environments), I guess it was just the way to typeset verbatim contents.

Later, Till added the more powerful fragile option:

> 2004-10-11 Till Tantau
>
> ```
> Version 3.01:
>
> Added:
> - Option "fragile" that allows the use of
>   overlays together with verbatims. *Extremely* useful.
> ```

The `fragile` option works by externalizing the frame's code into an own file (with suffix `.vrb`) and the overlay mechanism works by reading this file multiple times, which plays nicely together with verbatim contents. Of course, this is a lot slower than the `containsverbatim` approach, which therefore was kept and documented under the additional (and better understandable) option name `fragile=singleslide`. Section §8.1 (page 61) of the [beamer user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) explains it in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) At first, it didn't compile, and with a strange error to add to my despair. But I removed indentation before `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}` to replicate the exact conditions of your answer and now it runs. Is that normal for such a command to avoid identation in such a restrictive manner?

Comment: to be specific, only the `\end{frame}` part needs no space beforehand °_o

Comment: @Mog: Yes. beamer typesets these slides by moving them to an exernal file first (with extension `.vrb`). It needs a line with only the `\end{frame}` to reliably detect the end of the current frame for this mechanism. The beamer user guide §8.1 describes all the details.

Comment: I just figured that there is also a `fragile=singleframe` option, which behaves exactly like the (undocumented) `containsverbatim`. Maybe that is now the official (much better understandable) name for it.

Comment: @Daniel That's right, `fragile=singleframe` does exactly the same as `containsverbatim`: Both set `\beamer@containsverbatimtrue`, which causes `\let\beamer@howtotreatframe=\beamer@dosingleframe` (in [`beamerbaseframe.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaseframe.sty), l. 473). In other words, the slide consists only of one single frame, so `\pause` commands and so on are ignored.

Comment: @Daniel: I wish I could vote up twice for those extra precisions :)

Comment: @Daniel Excellent answer!

Comment: @Mog: You are welcome. Up-voting and accepting basically is up-voting twice :-)