# Can a beamer frame have both [containsverbatim] and hidden/shown block options?

Tags: beamer, verbatim, overlays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\pause won't generate extra slides in a containsverbatim frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55687/pause-wont-generate-extra-slides-in-a-containsverbatim-frame)

I use `lstlisting` environments in my beamer frames, but I would also like to have blocks with showing/hidden options like `<2>`, `<1-3>`, etc. With the following code, only the first version of the frame is displayed (with only the first block). Is there a way to make the hidden/shown block options work when the `[containsverbatim]` option is active?

```
\begin{frame}[containsverbatim]

  \begin{block}{}
    \begin{lstlisting}
blah blah blah
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}<2>{}
    \begin{lstlisting}
blah blah blah
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{block}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Please _do not use_ `containsverbatim`: it is a historical overhang and is _not in the documentation_ for a reason. The correct option is `fragile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can combine verbatim material and overlay specifications in your frames; only some precautions must be taken: to use verbatim material in a frame, you have to add the option `[fragile]` to the `frame` *environment* (with verbatim material, the `\frame` command will not do); the `\end{frame}` line must be alone on a single line:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{block}{}
\begin{lstlisting}
blah blah blah
\end{lstlisting}
\end{block}

\begin{block}<2>{}
\begin{lstlisting}
blah blah blah
\end{lstlisting}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about `containsverbatim` vs `fragile`. But how come I can't even indent `\end{frame}` when using `fragile`? I've always indented my LaTeX code (like any other code) and it would be hard for me to live without indentation... How can I do that?

Comment: I'll choose this answer, but IMO the situation is bugged, if "fragile" works only if no space or tabulation is used on a given LaTeX line.

Comment: Some time has passed, maybe there was an update, but I can indent as usual. I have not encountered any restrictions regarding `[fragile]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `lstlisting` and beamer's  `uncover` features. However you should not use `containsverbatim`. Instead there is an option to place the verbatim part before the `\begin{frame}` where it will not confuse the beamer features. You can find it in the documentation of the beamer class.

Comment: It would be great if you can make a minimal example using the OP's snippet to demonstrate how your answer works.