# Trying to get Tikz chains example working

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

I found a lovely example [of chains diagramming here](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/pgf-tikz-commutative-diagram/) and have been trying to get it to work.  I opened a fresh document [on WriteLaTeX, here](https://www.writelatex.com/285283dfjsgc), and put in the minimal preamble for the chains drawing, namely

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Chains}
  % http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/pgf-tikz-commutative-diagram/
  \tikzset{join/.code=\tikzset{after node path={%
  \ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
  edge[every join]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}} 

  \tikzset{>=stealth',every on chain/.append style={join},every join/.style={->}}         
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get an error that there is an illegal parameter *number* in the *definition* of `\test`, and that I meant to type `##` and not `#`, didn't I?

If I take out the `tikzset` lines, then the document compiles. I have the same problems in a non-`beamer` document.

I'm just using WriteLaTeX and don't have any tooling that will allow me to debug into the guts of `tikz` to search for an answer; I am only a noob user of `tikz`, taking working examples and tweaking them one thing at a time, backing off when they break; and lots of other `tikz` examples I have mined from the web work great. But this one I couldn't even get bootstrapped.

**EDIT:** Putting `[fragile]` after the `\begin{frame}` notation got me past the error. Now the following drawing doesn't look good (arrows don't draw; all the arrow labels pile up on one another at the beginning:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain] {
    \node[on chain] {$0$};
    \node[on chain] {$A$} ;
    \node[on chain, join={node[above]
          {$\scriptstyle\varphi$}}] {$B$};
    \node[on chain, join={node[above]
          {$\scriptstyle\psi$}}] {$C$};
    \node[on chain] {$0$}; }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Merging the two `tikzset` instructions and removing the `stealth'` sub-instruction had no effect on the appearance of the result.

Comment: There was an extra `\tikzset` in the code ;) I recommend `tikz-cd` package if this is going to be a commutative diagram.

Comment: Quite hard for me to mentally parse the code from the source web site: it does say `\tikzset{join/.code=\tikzset{after node path={%`, but, if I change it to `\tikzset{join/.code={after node path={%`, that doesn't work.  I fully admit I do not understand the syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a document that will compile:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,chains}

\begin{document}

% http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/pgf-tikz-commutative-diagram/

\makeatletter
\tikzset{join/.code=\tikzset{after node path={%
 \ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
 edge[every join]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}} 
\makeatother

\begin{frame}{Chains}
  \tikzset{>=stealth',every on chain/.append style={join},
  every join/.style={->}} 

  \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain] {
    \node[on chain] {$X$};
    \node[on chain, join={node[above] {$\scriptstyle f$}}] {$Y$};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

There were at least two problems with your code.

1. `#` in a beamer frame confuses the beamer parsing.  Instead you can move this `\tikzset` command outside of the frame.
2. The same code snippet contains an `@` sign and so needs to be enclosed in a `\makeatletter / \makeatother` pair.

The restrictions on frame contents are described in the beamer manual as follows

> The ⟨environment contents⟩ can be normal LATEX text, but may not contain `\verb` commands or verbatim environments or any environment that changes the character codes, unless the fragile option is given.

As `#` is not a normal text character, it is thus excluded from standard frame contents.  @Daniel points out that you can use the `fragile` option on the frame to work around this.  @Daniel further points out that this usable despite the description in the manual:

> If a frame contains fragile text, different internal mechanisms are used to typeset the frame to ensure that inside the frame the character codes can be reset. The price of switching to another internal mechanism is that either you cannot use overlays or an external file needs to be written and read back (which is not always desirable).

The code written to an external file, causing slightly slower compilation, but not loosing any overlay features.  See [@Daniel's answer to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55699/15925) for more information.

Comment: This one also renders correctly, so is a full answer!

Comment: If, however, you want to define the style locally (inside the frame), passing the `fragile` option to the frame environment should also help.

Comment: @Daniel I have added a little more to my answer discussing this.

Comment: "This looses you some beamer functionality" is not true for any practical purpose; the cited paragraph from the manual is misleading: Historically, beamer provided the `containsverbatim` option that had the mentioned [disadvantage of not supporting overlays](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55699/3751). However, with the newer `fragile`, the only disadvantage is a slight compilation-speed penalty caused by the detour over the extra file. For the average user, this probably is hardly noticeable.

Comment: @Daniel Nice - I have incorporated this into my answer.