# Verbatim inside a minipage inside a tikz node -- beamer class

Tags: tikz-pgf, verbatim

I am trying to get a boxed text as part of a tikz node. I found an example [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/) that I am trying to follow, but it is giving me an error: Argument of \@xverbatim has an extra }. I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is below. One interesting thing is that if I change the documentclass to article, it works. However, I need this in a beamer environment.

```
\documentclass[table,xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Testing verbatim}
   \tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=2pt, inner ysep=2pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \tiny
    \begin{verbatim}
<list title="MOVIES">
   <film>
      <title>The Shining</title>
      <release_date>1980-05-23</release_date>
      <director>Stanley Kubrick</director>
      <actor>Jack Nicholson</actor>
   </film>
   <film>
      <title>Spartacus</title>
      <director>Stanley Kubrick</director>
   </film>
   <film>
      <title>The Passenger</title>
      <actor>Jack Nicholson</actor>
   </film>
   ...
</list>
    \end{verbatim}
    \end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `[fragile]` option to `\begin{frame}`. I have also added the options `font=\tiny,text width=0.45\textwidth` to the `mybox` style.

Code:

```
\documentclass[table,xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
   \frametitle{Testing verbatim}
   \tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=2pt, inner ysep=2pt,font=\tiny,text width=0.45\textwidth]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{verbatim}
<list title="MOVIES">
   <film>
      <title>The Shining</title>
      <release_date>1980-05-23</release_date>
      <director>Stanley Kubrick</director>
      <actor>Jack Nicholson</actor>
   </film>
   <film>
      <title>Spartacus</title>
      <director>Stanley Kubrick</director>
   </film>
   <film>
      <title>The Passenger</title>
      <actor>Jack Nicholson</actor>
   </film>
   ...
</list>
    \end{verbatim}
    \end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another option with `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[table,xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable,fitting}

\newtcblisting{myverbatim}{
      arc=3mm,
      top=0mm,
      bottom=0mm,
      left=0mm,
      right=0mm,
      boxrule=1pt,
      colframe=red,
      colback=blue!20,
      listing only,
      listing options={
        basicstyle=\tiny
      },
      hbox,
      %width=0.6\textwidth,  %%For fitting library
      breakable
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
   \frametitle{Testing verbatim}
\pause
\begin{myverbatim}
<list title="MOVIES">
   <film>
      <title>The Shining</title>
      <release_date>1980-05-23</release_date>
      <director>Stanley Kubrick</director>
      <actor>Jack Nicholson</actor>
   </film>
   <film>
      <title>Spartacus</title>
      <director>Stanley Kubrick</director>
   </film>
   <film>
      <title>The Passenger</title>
      <actor>Jack Nicholson</actor>
   </film>
   ...
</list>
    \end{myverbatim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: Spoke too soon... I need to put the entire \begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{picture} inside an \only<2>{...}. When I do that I get the error again. I left that part out because I thought that would be simple. Any ideas to fix this please?

Comment: Related:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55687/pause-wont-generate-extra-slides-in-a-containsverbatim-frame

Comment: @ozsu Put a `\pause` before `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @ozsu I have added another option using `tcolorbox` that may of interest to you.